# How small is too small to fragment cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When fragment caching non-dynamic html in Rails

```
<% cache [:long_list] do %>
  <li><!-- Loads of html --></li>
  <li><!-- Loads of html --></li>
  <li><!-- Loads of html --></li>
  <!-- Loads more li items... -->
<% end %>
```

In terms of the size of the content being cached, is there a point at which caching will result in a decrease in page rendering speed?

Ir more succinctly, is this likely to reduce performance?

```
<% cache :div do %>
  <div id="empty-content"></div>
<% end %>
```

Assume the user of an in-memory cache such as memcached.

Comment: I'm pretty sure cache wins or is equivalent but you should simply profile it using dev mode with in memory cache: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html#generating-performance-tests

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense to cache static content as these templates are precompiled and cached anyway in production - they are, in-fact, in memory.

Comment: Even if other parts of the page are generated with ERB? I didn't mean to imply that the whole page was static.

Comment: Well, when ERB template is compiled, it basically becomes a list of "_erbout.concat" method calls. The method takes a string as its argument or something that results in string - so your static parts are just static strings that get passed along, your dynamic parts are dynamic and result in string. So bottom line, the static parts are already there, no need to get them from some external storage.